# How can I review all database and object grants for a role?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to audit all of the permissions for an application before release and I want to ensure no role has more access than it needs. I have looked at the different functions and system tables, but everything is very piecemeal.

Is there a good query or method to be able to dump out every grant a particular role has?

I am using pg 9.5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The column `relacl` of the system catalog `pg_class` contains all informations on privileges.

Example data in schema `public` owned by `postgres` with grants to `newuser`:

```
create table test(id int);
create view test_view as select * from test;

grant select, insert, update on test to newuser;
grant select on test_view to newuser;
```

Querying the `pg_class`:

```
select 
    relname, 
    relkind, 
    coalesce(nullif(s[1], ''), 'public') as grantee, 
    s[2] as privileges
from 
    pg_class c
    join pg_namespace n on n.oid = relnamespace
    join pg_roles r on r.oid = relowner,
    unnest(coalesce(relacl::text[], format('{%s=arwdDxt/%s}', rolname, rolname)::text[])) acl, 
    regexp_split_to_array(acl, '=|/') s
where nspname = 'public'
and relname like 'test%';

  relname  | relkind | grantee  | privileges 
-----------+---------+----------+------------
 test      | r       | postgres | arwdDxt      <- owner postgres has all privileges on the table
 test      | r       | newuser  | arw          <- newuser has append/read/write privileges
 test_view | v       | postgres | arwdDxt      <- owner postgres has all privileges on the view
 test_view | v       | newuser  | r            <- newuser has read privilege
(4 rows)
```

Comments:

- `coalesce(relacl::text[], format('{%s=arwdDxt/%s}', rolname, rolname))` - Null in `relacl` means that the owner has all privileges;
- `unnest(...) acl` - `relacl` is an array of `aclitem`, one array element for a user;
- `regexp_split_to_array(acl, '=|/') s` - split `aclitem` into: s[1] username, s[2] privileges;
- `coalesce(nullif(s[1], ''), 'public') as grantee` - empty username means `public`.

Modify the query to select individual user or specific kind of relation or another schemas, etc...

Read in the documentation:

- [The catalog `pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/catalog-pg-class.html),
- [`GRANT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-grant.html) with the description of acl system.

In a similar way you can get information about privileges granted on schemas (the column [`nspacl` in `pg_namespace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/catalog-pg-namespace.html)) and databases ([`datacl` in `pg_database`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/catalog-pg-database.html))

Comment: This is great.  I was spending too much time using the has_xxx_privilege() functions and the various pg_tables, pg_proc, etc. tables and views.

Comment: Note that while this does show the implicit grants for the owner of the table, it does not show the implicit grants for superusers.

Answer (score 1):

The `relacl` column (and others of type `aclitem`) doesn't have to be parsed as text.
The function `aclexplode` unnests array, which makes it suitable for lateral join. Result is record with well named fields, just convert oid to human-readable name:

```
select c.*, n.nspname,
  acl.grantor, acl.grantee,
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(acl.grantor), pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(acl.grantee),
  acl.privilege_type, acl.is_grantable
from pg_catalog.pg_class c
join pg_catalog.pg_namespace n on n.oid = c.relnamespace,
lateral aclexplode(c.relacl) acl;
```

Comment: The function has not been officially documented, its description is likely to be found in the Postgres 12 documentation.