# python psycopg2 postgresql: getting "permission denied for relation settings"

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have been through [numerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595560/postgresql-permission-denied-for-relation) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645361/psycopg2-programmingerror-permission-denied-for-relation-django-migrations) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520361/permission-denied-for-relation) (to name only a few) but still stuck. The configuration is simple enough that I'll detail everything, though I think only a few of the following are relevant:

Running `psql` as user *postgres* on Ubuntu 16.04, I've created database *qedadmin* with 3 tables: *networks*, *devices*, and *settings*; there's also a sequence relation *networks_networkid_seq* owned by *networks.networkId*.

I am writing a python script to run on the same server using psycopg2 which needs to execute a `SELECT` on the *settings* table. Many examples show scripts connecting as user '*postgres*', and indeed this works perfectly for me. However, I suppose it's better to use a less-privileged user for this sort of thing, so I created a user *qedserver* with a password.

Using this new user and password and localhost in the psycopg2 connection string, I can successfully get a connection and a cursor (and if I use incorrect user or password values, the connection fails, so I know the defined user and password and the authentication from python are all working). However, all of my attempts to execute a `SELECT` statement on table *settings* are returning code 42501: permission denied for relation settings.

I initially granted user *qedserver* only `SELECT` privileges, and only on table *settings*:

```
GRANT SELECT ON settings TO qedserver;
```

Since that did not work, I've gradually escalated privileges to the point that now user *qedserver* has ALL PRIVILEGES on all 3 tables, on the sequence relation, and on the database:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON settings TO qedserver;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON devices TO qedserver;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON networks TO qedserver;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON networks_networkid_seq TO qedserver;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE qedadmin TO qedserver;
```

but I am still getting "permission denied for relation settings".

To be clear, changing just the connection string in my python script from one for user *postgres* to one for user *qedserver* makes the difference between success and failure, so I am not providing python code because I think it's irrelevant (but I can do so if you think it would help).

What am I missing?

Edited to add: there is no linux user named *qedserver*; I don't think there needs to be but perhaps I'm wrong about that? (further edit: I just did this experiment and it made no difference.)

**Updates:** Per @klin's comment and link, I can see that all of the privileges have been successfully granted: qedserver has privileges `arwdDxt` on the *networks*, *devices*, and *settings* tables, and `rwU` privileges on the *networks_networkid_seq* sequence relation; and `\l` reports Access Privileges on the *qedadmin* database of `=Tc/postgres + postgres=CTc/postgres + qedserver=CTc/postgres`.

I have also edited the config file (/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf on my system) to set log_error_verbosity=VERBOSE and sent a SIGHUP to the postgresql process to re-read the config file. This added another line to the error log (/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log on my system) for each failed attempt; now the log shows (the new line is the middle one):

```
qedserver@qedadmin ERROR:  42501: permission denied for relation settings
qedserver@qedadmin LOCATION:  aclcheck_error, aclchk.c:3410
qedserver@qedadmin STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM settings WHERE deviceId = 10020;
```

What else can I look at or try to make headway?

**Editing 4 months later to add:** this was all for a new project for which I thought it would be advantageous to use postgresql for a few reasons; hitting this problem so early in development and being unable to resolve it over several days, I gave up and went with mysql instead. Not exactly a "solution" to the OP so I'm not adding it as an answer...

Comment: Basically this should be enough: `grant select on settings to qedserver;` It seems that for some reason the `grant` commands have no effect. Use the query described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39820032/1995738) to check whether the user actually has privileges granted.

Comment: I need more time to absorb that post and make sure I understand it, but doing a quick test of that query minus the WHERE clause returns nothing at all... If it turns out to be the case that `GRANT` is having no effect, what would my options be at that point?

Comment: The query without the `WHERE` clause should return at least one row per each relation, so something is really wrong. Did you run it in `psql`? What tool do you use for plain sql?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot a terminal semicolon after the paste! I'm getting results now... will take me some moments to look it all over...

Comment: WHERE s[1] = 'qedserver' yields 4 rows: 1 for each table w/ privileges arwdDxt and 1 for the sequence relation w/ privileges rwU; nothing for the db itself... would the db privileges show up in this query w/ that WHERE clause? It appears all the table privs are fine, so unless it's db privs I don't know where to look next.

Comment: It's really puzzling, it's hard to say anything. I've found this: [Postgres permission denied](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/873174.35146.qm@web54409.mail.yahoo.com)